# Embed forum software (phpBB, MyBB, ...) into static website frameworks (Jekyll, Middleman, ...)

Tags: html, jekyll, forum, middleman, static-site

I like the idea behind static site generators like Jekyll/Middleman/Hexo/Hugo etc. and I'm currently running my website using Middleman. Being new to web development in general, there is one thing about them that isn't clear to me: How can I embed a forum software like phpBB, MyBB, SMF, or Vanilla Forum into a page generated by a static generator framework? By embedding I mean: How to share things like a header/navbar/footer between the regular pages and the forum page.

A quick Google search only gave suggestions like:

- Embed the forum in a frame/iframe, along with the general warning that frames are bad and this may have negative side effects.
- Solving the embedding the other way around, that is, by modeling the website's header/footer as a "theme" in the forum software -- in some cases even by just taking screenshots of the website elements.

Both approaches aren't really convincing, so my question is: Is there a nicer solution to this?

If there is no general answer and it largely depends on which combination of generator + forum software: Is there any combination which has a specific solution to this and works particularly well?

Comment: Sounds like you're describing an `iframe`.

Comment: Note that it is the `Frame` that is bad, not an iframe.  The iframe is the kinder, gentler replacement for a frame.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's very well possible, thanks! In this case the question would if the warnings of negative side effects apply to iframes as well?

Comment: There are downsides to iframes. First of all the iframe would hide the requested URL, which makes sharing a link to a specific page in your forum impossible/harder. Secondly, the iframe could be loaded seperately, which might be unwanted (and could/should be prevented with javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to create a similar theme (as suggested in your question). However, you could try to read the header div and the footer div of the static site with PHP and echo them in your forum template. That would be more complicated to achieve, but completely DRY.

Comment: Do you have some experience with any of the common forum frameworks how much work that is? What if the header contains fancy javascript animations? How much effort is it to transfer a future modification of the header/navbar into the theme? The idea of having to take screenshots any time I modify my main site does not sound very convenient.

Comment: Just load the js and css required (you can link the originals) and you should be good. Keeping the theme up-to-date is not DRY. The amount of work seems clear to me. Any change needs to be duplicated.